# How to integrate AWS C++ SDK into ESP-IDF project?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, iot

I'd like to integrate [AWS C++ SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/tree/release) into a new ESP-IDF project, as a component. As I can see the AWS one uses CMake as opposed to ESP-IDF which uses "old-style" `component.mk` (I'm not sure how it is called).

I tried using [ESP-IDF cmake branch](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/feature/cmake) and configuring stuff together with no luck. It is all vague to me.

Other way could be to migrate AWS C++ SDK onto the ESP-IDF's "old-style" platform. I'd prefer this as there are other libs using this style so that they don't have to be ported.

Question, which way to go? How to do it? What are the steps to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**

I've decided to go for the ESP-IDF / "old-style" way. What I've done so far is to create folder `components/aws-iot` where I cloned the AWS-SDK, created a `component.mk` [similarly to this](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/components/aws_iot), with the following content:

```
COMPONENT_ADD_INCLUDEDIRS := aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/network/OpenSSL /usr/local/opt/openssl/include
COMPONENT_SRCDIRS := aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src
COMPONENT_SUBMODULES := aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp
```

I took the PubSub example and copied it into my project's main folder. When I'm compiling it throws an error: `components/aws-iot/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/network/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConnection.hpp:41:25: fatal error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Note that I added OpenSSL's include dir but it seems to be ignoring it. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do?  Do you want something like an ESP32 directly calling a Lambda or something?  The ESP toolkit has example [AWS IoT](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/protocols/aws_iot) code that works well.

Comment: I'd like to use the C++ SDK, not the C one if possible.